# Does an empirical distribution converge to the underlying distribution?

Tags: probability-distributions, reference-request, weak-convergence

Let $\mu_n$ be an empirical distribution of $n$-iid points from the underlying distribution $\mu$.

In 1D, it is well-known by [Kolmogorov's theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kolmogorov%E2%80%93Smirnov_test), [Glivenko–Cantelli](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Glivenko%E2%80%93Cantelli_theorem) theorem that
for any $x$, let $E_x = (-\infty, x]$. Then 
$$
\lim_{n\to \infty} \sup_{x \in \mathbb{R}}|\mu_n(E_x)-\mu(E_x)| = 0 \quad (a.s.)
$$
and 
$$
\lim_{n\to \infty} \sqrt{n}\sup_{x\in \mathbb{R}}|\mu_n(E_x) - \mu(E_x)| \overset{d}{=}\sup_{t \in [0,1]} |B(t)|
$$
where $B(t)$ is the [Brownian bridge](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Brownian_bridge).
In $d$-dimension, are there analogous results for this? If yes, I am looking for a reference of this result.

Any comments/answers/suggestions will be very appreciated.

Comment: Well a empirical distribution is a random variable so $|\mu_n\mu|$ is also a random variable, this means that depending on the initial distribution this may never be true for any event and hence you cannot conclude. Could you specify the type of convergence you use for $\lim_{n\to\infty} \mu_n=\mu$ and also if you mean $\mathbb P[\exists C>0~,~|\mu_n-\mu|\leq C*n^{-1/2}]=1$

Comment: @P.Quinton You are absolutely right. I added the type of convergence. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

The concept of VC-Dimension precisely generalizes this phenomenon. If a set of functions has finite VC Dimension, such statments would hold. In higher dimensions you can look at the set of indicator functions of cuboids $ \mathcal{F} = \{ E_{x_1,\dots,x_d} : x_1, \dots, x_d \in \mathbb{R} \} $ where $E_{x_1,\dots,x_d}(y_1,\dots,y_d) = \prod_{i=1}^d E_{x_i}(y_i)$.
It can be shown $\mathcal{F}$ has finite VC-Dimension. (I don't remember exactly but somewhere between $d$  and $2d$).

You can consult Chapter 8 of HDP[1] for the first kind of convergence results. For a Donsker Theorem, you can consult Shorack and Wellner[2].

[1]: High-Dimensional Probability, Roman Vershynin. https://www.math.uci.edu/~rvershyn/papers/HDP-book/HDP-book.html

[2]: Empirical Processes with Applications to Statistics, Galen R. Shorack and Jon August Wellner.